# JavaFx with strange border in List

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I have a JavaFX list using flowless project. But I get a strange border (I have not enabled any border and forced the border to have width=0px) that is present and has a gradient effect:

[image: List with strange border that has a gradient]

When I set the cell background-inset to -1, the border is gone, so I believe this issue is related to the background. Although this is not a solution because if I enable the border (which I want to), the gradient effect is still present.

Does anyone knows how I can get rid of this border?

I use JavaFX 8 with latest 201 release.

EDIT: I made the following example show casing the issue:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.fxmisc.flowless.Cell;
import org.fxmisc.flowless.VirtualFlow;
import org.fxmisc.flowless.VirtualizedScrollPane;

public class Main extends Application {

  private ObservableList<Line> logLines;

  private VirtualFlow<Line, Cell<Line, LineCell>> listView;

  private VirtualizedScrollPane<VirtualFlow> listScrollPane;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    logLines = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for(int i=1; i < 50; i++) {
      logLines.add(new Line("Line "+i));
    }

    listView = VirtualFlow.createVertical(logLines, (line) -> Cell.wrapNode(new LineCell(line)));
    listScrollPane = new VirtualizedScrollPane<>(listView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(listScrollPane, 200, 600, Color.BLACK);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }


  private class Line {

    private String text;

    public Line(String text) {
      this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
      return text;
    }
  }

  private class LineCell extends TextFlow {
    public LineCell(Line line) {
      super();
      Text t = new Text(line.getText());
      t.setFill(Color.BLACK);
      super.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
      super.getChildren().add(t);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have this same issue. Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: Hi @DoombringerBG, I have posted the solution

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to this issue. Instead of LineCell extending TextFlow, it now extends StackPane and I add the TextFlow to the Stackpane.

```
  private class LineCell extends StackPane {
    public LineCell(Line line) {
      super();
      Text t = new Text(line.getText());
      t.setFill(Color.BLACK);

      TextFlow tf = new TextFlow(t);
      super.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
      super.getChildren().add(tf);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. :3